# Filtering on managed metadata columns in the insert link from SharePoint view throws invalid viewstate error

Tags: document-library, error, filter, sharepoint-server, viewstate

I've seen this error before in SharePoint 2010 and now in SharePoint 2013 (w/SP1), and it should be pretty straightforward to reproduce using the following steps:

1. Create a document library
2. Add one or more managed metadata columns to the library, and add them to the default view. You can add Wiki Categories for instace.
3. Create a page (type of page shouldn't matter - I use enterprise wiki) in the same site.
4. On the page, in the ribbon select *Insert Link -> From SharePoint*
5. Navigate to the document library you have created.
6. Try to filter any of the managed metadata columns in the view.
7. Exception is thrown. The URL of the page that throws the error is /_layouts/15/AssetPortalBrowser.aspx?List=38580a7e%2Da25f%2D42b8%2Dacaf%2Dc4f6668bc8ca&MDWeb=7ef5e112%2Dbf9b%2D4c2d%2Da838%2D468611386b26&AssetType=Link&IsDlg=1&View={2A981D4B-1DC8-46E6-8DCF-FDD587E013FB}&FilterField1=Wiki%5Fx0020%5FPage%5Fx0020%5FCategories&FilterValue1=16&FilterOp1=In&FilterLookupId1=1&FilterData1=0%2C7fe9532f%2D3767%2D400d%2Da4e2%2D373ec2af4a0f

The error from ULS is

```
System.Web.UI.ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate.    
Client IP: 111.22.123.44
Port: 62711   
Referer: https://mysite.com/MyPage.aspx
Path: /_layouts/15/AssetPortalBrowser.aspx   
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.3; MALCJS)
ViewState: 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
```

Anyone seen it before or have suggestions for fix?

Comment: I have exact the same issue. It seems like SP OOB bug. BTW as SP1 is supposed to fix filtering on managed metadata column in the list view, hopefully, this issue might be fixed by SP1 as well...

Comment: I have SP1 and the issue persist

Comment: All I've found so far is this blog post: http://blog.tippoint.net/tag/asset-picker/. However, it does not work for me, unfortunately.